# Chef server - permissions to specific cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

Does chef-server have any way to allow/disallow downloading specific cookbook? Let us say, organization has few projects and there are cookbooks installing environment for them. I would like to set client A permission to download only A cookbook and B - only B.

Maybe this could be achieved by creating multpiple organizations, for example per project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this problem using [knife-acl](https://github.com/chef/knife-acl) plugin - it can add **client** (not only user) to chef-server group - you can use this group later to set permissions. I couldn't do it with `chef-manage` (2.5.4) using browser (couldn't find any way to add client to group).

Example of giving permissions to download cookbook only for clients from specific cookbook:

```
# Creating new group
knife group create my-group

# Remove global permissions for all clients in specific cookbook
knife acl remove group clients cookbooks my-cookbook create,read,update,delete,grant

# Add permissions to download cookbook for clients from new group
knife acl bulk add group my-group cookbooks '^my-cookbook$' read --yes

# Add client to new group
knife group add client my-client my-group
```

To download `knife-acl` plugin you have to install [ChefDK](https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk) and install this plugin with command:

```
chef gem install knife-acl
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.chef.io/auth.html has a full overview of the Chef Server ACL system. Setting up what you describe would be incredibly complex but is theoretically possible. Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: I'm planning to set up dev environments using Chef (IDE, servers etc.) per project - to speed up process of configuring workstation for developer. They should not have access to cookbooks that are created for projects other than their allowed projects.

Comment: You probably want to make multiple organizations then.